# Error: Module not found for zip created through pipeline for lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, gitlab-ci

I am trying to deploy a python fastapi application on AWS lambda.
I am using the below folder structure for zip file created where app has the application code.

```
--app
   --routers
       --router.py
   --main.py
   --__init__.py
--dependency1
--dependency2
```

If I zip up the dependencies and function code and use the zip, lambda function works fine.
But the same zip file created through pipeline throws error.
On comparing the zip files created through pipeline and the other one that was created using 7z, I found out there was a difference in file permissions.

As per the AWS docs,I have also updated the file permissions for files within app directory. But I still get the same error.

```
 {
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app.main': No module named 'app'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
 }
```

Runtime : **python3.8**

handler : **app.main.handler**

I went through multiple issues on SO and GitHub but could not find anything specific to my issue. Hope someone might have encountered this error at some point. Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Since the problem seems to be the zip file, could you provide more details aout how you're creating the zip file in the pipeline?

Comment: @ssoBAekiLThe issue was with file permission for app directory in the above structure in zip file being created. So before creating the zip I updated the file permissions to 755 and now it works fine.